# How would I use django.forms to prepopulate a choice field with rows from a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ChoiceField in my form class, presumably a list of users. How do I prepopulate this with a list of users from my User model?

What I have now is:

```
class MatchForm(forms.Form):

  choices = []

  user1_auto = forms.CharField()
  user1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
  user2_auto = forms.CharField()
  user2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)

  def __init__(self):
      user_choices = User.objects.all()
      for choice in user_choices:
          self.choices.append(
              (choice.id, choice.get_full_name())
          )
```

This doesn't seem to work (otherwise I wouldn't be here). Thoughts?

To clarify, when I attempt to render this form in a template, it simply outputs nothing, unless I remove the ChoiceFields and `__init__()` method.

Also, what if I only want a list of the users' full names in my field? That is, I'd like to control the display output of each user object (so `ModelChoiceField` isn't really an option).

Comment: Why aren't you using a ForeignKey for this?  A drop-down list that refers to a table is what an FK is.  Why not use that?

Comment: The form simply won't render unless I remove the custom __init__.py and ChoiceFields.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It looks like you may be looking for [`ModelChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField).

```
user2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

This won't show fullnames, though, it'll just call `__unicode__` on each object to get the displayed value.

Where you don't just want to display `__unicode__`, I do something like this:

```
class MatchForm(forms.Form):
    user1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user1'].choices = [(x.pk, x.get_full_name()) for x in User.objects.all()]
```

Comment: what do I do if I need the fullnames rather than `__unicode__`?

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score -3):

```
class MatchForm(forms.Form):
  choices = tuple(User.objects.all().values_list())

  user1_auto = forms.CharField()
  user1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
  user2_auto = forms.CharField()
  user2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

This should work.

Comment: It isn't dynamic though. The first time that code is run, the list of users will be set forever, and any Users added later will not appear in the form.

Comment: @Dominic What do you mean by 'not dynamic'? Will this refresh the list of users every time I use the form?

Comment: @Sri - no. Per my previous comment - the first time that code is run, the list of Users will be set forever, and any Users added later will not appear in the form, most likely until your webserver is restarted.