# Django populating form field from another app model

Tags: django, django-forms

i have two apps first is inputs and second is boq
inputs contains a model building
boq contains a model boq model
My inputs model looks like

```
class building(models.Model):

    building = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

My boq model looks like

```
class boqmodel(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    building =models.CharField(max_length=300)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    subactivity = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    duration=models.IntegerField()
    linkactivity= models.CharField(max_length=300)
    linktype= models.CharField(max_length=300)
    linkduration=models.IntegerField()
    plannedstart=models.DateField()
    plannedfinish=models.DateField()
    actualstart=models.DateField()
    actualfinish=models.DateField()
```

i have aform in boq

```
class boqform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = boqmodel
        fields=['code',
            'building',
            'level',
            'activity',
            'subactivity',
            'duration',
            'linkactivity',
            'linktype',
            'linkduration',
            'plannedstart',
            'plannedfinish',
            'actualstart',
            'actualfinish']
```

Now in my boqform for field building i need the form to have a dropdown from values in building model

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4593322/3140312

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I use django.forms to prepopulate a choice field with rows from a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593292/how-would-i-use-django-forms-to-prepopulate-a-choice-field-with-rows-from-a-mode)