# Getting an ID (pk) from model.py in django-forms. Bad performance

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

I can't get the id through the form. I would like to pass variables to SpotifyData but they cannot be "name" values. I need to pass "id" variables.

I also have another problem with ArtistForm. I have 90000 different artists in the Artist model so it takes a very long time to load the page using this form (it has to load all this values into the choicefield list)

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Region(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rank(models.Model):

    name = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Chart(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Artist(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Title(models.Model):

    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.artist} - {self.name}"
    

class SpotifyData(models.Model):

    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chart = models.ForeignKey(Chart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    streams = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title) + ", " + str(self.date) + ", " + str(self.artist) \
            + ", " + str(self.region) + ", " + str(self.chart) + ", " + str(self.streams)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *
from spotify_data.models import (Region,
                                 Rank,
                                 Chart,
                                 Artist,
                                 Title,
                                 SpotifyData)

class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    FROM = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}), initial="2019-01-01")
    TO = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}), initial="2020-01-01")
    
class Artist1Form(forms.Form):

    ARTIST = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=[], widget=forms.Select,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Artist1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ARTIST'].choices = Artist.objects.values("name").\
            values_list("name","name")

class Title1Form(forms.Form):
    TITLE = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'charfield'}), initial="bad guy")

class Artist2Form(forms.Form):
    ARTIST_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'charfield'}))

class Title2Form(forms.Form):
    TITLE_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'charfield'}))

class ChartForm(forms.Form):
    CHART = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=[], widget=forms.Select,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['CHART'].choices = Chart.objects.values("name").\
            values_list("name","name")

class RegionForm(forms.Form):
    REGION = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=[], widget=forms.Select,)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['REGION'].choices = Region.objects.values("name").\
            values_list("name","name")
```

and views.py

```
class SongRankChangesChart(TemplateView):

    model = SpotifyData
    context_object_name = "rank_changes"
    
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        
        start = self.request.GET.get("FROM")
        end = self.request.GET.get("TO")
        artist = self.request.GET.get("ARTISTG")
        title = self.request.GET.get("TITLE")
        region = self.request.GET.get("REGION")
        chart = self.request.GET.get("CHART")
        

        chart_id = Chart.objects.filter(name=chart["name"]).values("id")

        data_filtered = SpotifyData.objects.filter(date__range=(start, end), artist = artist, title = title
                            , region=region, chart=chart_id).values()
       
        data = data_filtered.values_list("date", "rank")
       
        fig = make_song_rank_changes_chart(data, start, end, artist, title)

        chart = fig.to_html()


        context = {"chart": chart,
                "daterange_form": DateRangeForm(),
                "artist1_form": Artist1Form(),
                "title1_form": Title1Form(),
                "chart_form": ChartForm(),
                "region_form": RegionForm(),
                "region_form":RegionForm(),  
                "df":data_filtered             
        }

        return context
```

I tried on the example of "chart" to get the id but this way did not work.

Data example:

```
title,rank,date,artist,region,chart,streams
Chantaje (feat. Maluma),1,2017-01-01,Shakira,Argentina,top200,253019
Vente Pa' Ca (feat. Maluma),2,2017-01-01,Ricky Martin,Argentina,top200,223988
Reggaetón Lento (Bailemos),3,2017-01-01,CNCO,Argentina,top200,210943
Safari,4,2017-01-01,"J Balvin, Pharrell Williams, BIA, Sky",Argentina,top200,173865
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I use django.forms to prepopulate a choice field with rows from a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593292/how-would-i-use-django-forms-to-prepopulate-a-choice-field-with-rows-from-a-mode) Simply use a `ModelChoiceField` if you want to stick with a `ChoiceField` actually use the id / pk of the object instead of something else for the value (the first value of the choice tuple)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you! I did as you mentioned. Could you also advise me on how to deal with the second problem? Is it possible to make a form that does not display the whole list but dynamically loads new values?

Comment: You should look at various packages that help implemeting a searchable / autocomplete supported choice field.